# How to create a new page with angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have install an amazing admin project made with angular 2.
Here is the demo of the project http://akveo.com/ng2-admin/#/pages/dashboard
I have problem to create a single new page in this project !
Here you can find what I want to do
https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/articles/013-create-new-page/
My error on my project is this one:
**pages.component.ts?7a77:76 Uncaught ReferenceError: New is not defined**
So basically I have a component problem, mys project can not find the component I am trying to used. In the page src/app/pages/pages.component.ts I have insert the following line ( as describe in the tutorial https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/articles/013-create-new-page/ )

```js
  {
    name: 'New',
    component: New, // here is the error
    path: '/new',
  }
```

If you want, you can install the project by using their tutorial: 
https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: did you add `export class New` to your 'new.component.module.js'?

Comment: Yes I add the export class New. But as candidJ mentioned on this answer, I had a problem with my import...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import the `New` component created in `pages/new` into `pages` component

so in your `src/app/pages/pages.component.ts` file add this:

```
import {New} from './new/new.component' //<---

@RouteConfig([
  // ... some routes here
  {
    name: 'New',
    component: New,
    path: '/new',
  }
])
export class Pages {
}
```